# Why does the file in a subdirectory not get copied?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cp

I have to make a script which will copy all files from a certain location starting with "db." to another location. My script works fine for all files which are directly in the directory, but it doesnt copy any files which are in subdirectorys. I have used the parameter -r, which should copy everything recursivly or not? Why isnt it working and how can I make it work?

My script:

```
#! /bin/bash

#Script zum kopieren aller Dateien welche mit "db." beginnen.

#User input
echo -n 'Enter path to copy from: '
read copypath

echo -n 'Enter path to save to: '
read savepath

cp -r $copypath/db.* $savepath

echo 'Done.
```

Comment: try `$copypath/db.*` followed by `$copypath/**/db.*`

Comment: You can use find command:

`find $copypath -type f -name "db.*" -exec cp {} $savepath \;`

Comment: @Siddharth it won't work for top level files situated in `$copypath/`

Comment: @Ursescu Ionut, both the commands issued would work, I suppose. First for the top level, second for all the subdirectories?

Comment: I guess Ursescu Ionu was mislead by  `a/**/b` which *looks* like there has to be a directory between `a` and `b`. However, that globstar also matches `a/b`.

Comment: @Socowi, you are right, having globstar activated will behave as expected, but note that without globstar `a/**/b` will be translated to `a/*/b`, which is wrong.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an answer out of my comment...

try `$copypath/db.*` followed by `$copypath/**/db.*`

The first one is for the top level directory (copypath) and the next for any of the subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

`-r` does not work here because you don't supply any source *directories* to `cp`.

Before `cp` is executed `bash` expands the `*` and gives the resulting file list to `cp`. `cp` then only sees something like `cp -r 1stFile 2ndFile 3rdFile ... targetDirectory` -- therefore `-r` has no effect.

As pointed out in the comments, you have to use `bash`'s globstar feature `**` or `find`. Also, you should make a habit of quoting your variables.

```
# requires bash 4.0 or higher (from the year 2009, but OS X has a really outdated version)
shopt -s globstar
cp "$copypath"/**/db.* "$savepath"
```

or

```
find "$copypath" -type f -name 'db.*' -exec cp -t "$savepath" {} +
```

Comment: Or you can use something like this `find "$copypath" -type f -name "db.*" | xargs cp -t "$savepath"`

Comment: @Bogdan Stoica What would be the advantage of `xargs` here? I suspect it would be slower and less safe (think of filenames with spaces or even newlines).

Comment: You're right indeed, I was just saying that's a possible option as well, nothing else...